# Low current cut off?

Tags: dc, amperage

I have a 5VDC circuit that I want to be cut off if "lower than X amps" is going through the load. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Smells like XY-problem. Mind to describe the X one?

Comment: Sense resistor + comparator + mosfet. But then you probably want a RS latch somewhere too, because otherwise it will never turn on (you didn't specify how it turns on, by the way). But I mostly agree with @Eugene.

Comment: I am expecting a current around 0.8-1.0 amps through the load, I would like the circuit to be cut if the current is lower than 0.5 amp and be up again as soon as it passes 0.5.

Comment: in order to "pass" 0.5 it should start with something lower, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'll repeat what Eugene already asked but.. what is it you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: You'll probably have to make an active circuit that probes the load to see if it can reach your load range given some _defined_ period of time to do so. If it fails, you can shut off and wait some other period of time before trying again. So it will probably be periodically ON when OFF, with some defined duty cycle you want, and ON fully when the criteria remains met. There will also be a time you still need to wait before turning OFF, too, in case the load temporarily requires less than your range but is still "good" as far as you are concerned. You need to define ALL of these details.

Answer (score -1):

- You will have to measure the current
- If the current is < than you want, switch a MOSFET or Relais, which is in your circuit

To measure the current there are different methods. You can use a "shunt" sense-resistor in your circuit - with an opamp, or an "current-sense-amplifier" for example. By integrating a low-resistance "shunt" resistor (R) into your circuit, and measuring the voltage (U) across this resistor, you can calculate the current via ohm's law, I=U/R. This sense-resistor usually only has a few milliohms in resistance, so it doesn't 'use' your circuits voltage. That's why you usually want to use an amplifier, because the voltage across the resistor is quite little.

To switch a MOSFET (for example), you could use an opamp/comparator, or - if you know some basic Arduino coding - you can use an Arduino for that and go the easy road.

There are still some unknown parameters, for example the current you are expecting in your circuit, if your circuit is supposed to draw 0 current after it switches off,...

[image: very basic circuit]

Comment: Allright, now I understand a bit thanks to you. As far as I understand, for e.g. if I try to manipulate the circuit, I can use 10ohm resistor and a "5V normally closed relay" to switch it at 0.5amp, is this correct? When the circuit is running this way, does the resistor and relay consume power? I am expecting zero draw when the circuit is cut.

Comment: _Relais_ heißt auf Englisch _relay_.